# Unity Rigidbody move in one directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the play to holding mouse button 1 and hold, so they go in one direction, but the player can still rotate the player when they are holding click.

[Link to my pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jfBH3hSy)

```
MovementController.cs Controls the character movements
Straight.cs On click makes the character, go in a straight line
```

How would I make it so the player can not rotate while they are holding mouse button 0? I have tried freezing rotation, and rb.Sleep(). Neither of those worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rigidbody.freezeRotation`, `RigidBody.Sleep()` and `Rigidbody.constraints` **only** forbid the Rigidbody from being rotated when the rotation happens a result of **a force** being applied.

So it will only stop a rotation from something like `Rigidbody.AddTorque` or from a collision.

Setting `Rigidbody.rotation` or calling `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` will always work regardless of freeze state, constraints or sleep because they mutate the rotation directly; they do not apply a force.

If you want to use `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` or `Rigidbody.rotation` or any `Transform` method, freezing the rotation of the rigidbody or adding constraints won't help. So instead, in `MovementControls` get `mousedown` the way you do in `Straight` and set the rotation only if it's false, like this:

```cs
if (!mousedown)
{
    currentRotation.x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
    currentRotation.y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
    currentRotation.x = Mathf.Repeat(currentRotation.x, 360);
    currentRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.y, -maxYAngle, maxYAngle);
    rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation.y, currentRotation.x, 0);
}
```

Comment: Neither rb.freezeRotation = true or rb.constraints worked.

Comment: @Pizzarules668 I maybe misunderstood what you want to accomplish - this will indeed freeze rotation, I just tested it out. The problem might also be that your code doesn't correctly deal with the input. In the code you pasted you're forgetting to set mousedown to false. `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` should be in an if/else statement where the else sets mousedown = false. Without this correction after clicking once, the click will be essentially "stuck" on.

Comment: I have one script that controls the player's movement (wasd, and an fps like camera controller with the mouse) and another script that on mouse click will push the player relative forwards but not be able to look around and aim where they are being pushed. Sorry If i was not clear, this is my second time making a question.

Comment: @pizzarules668 how are you rotating the player? Rigidbody freeze and constraint only prevents the Rigidbody from being rotated by _physics_ methods. It won't stop a GameObject from being rotated by Transform methods as far as I know.

Comment: I am using rb.Rotate(), to rotate the player I have made a Pastebin to show you all of the code. https://pastebin.com/jfBH3hSy

Comment: @Pizzarules668 thanks, that clarifies things a lot. I heavily edited my answer in response. Would you please edit your question as well to include the pastebin code? It will help future readers understand better.

Comment: Thank you I am sorry that is was hard for you to understand what I was trying to accomplish. I am new to stackoverflow.